# Chropleth map isn't showing what I want

Tags: python, json, numpy, folium

```
threshold_scale = np.linspace(df_value_counts['Count'].min(),
                              df_value_counts['Count'].max(),
                              6, dtype=int)
threshold_scale = threshold_scale.tolist() 
threshold_scale[-1] = threshold_scale[-1] + 1 

sf_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=sf_geo,
    data=df_value_counts,
    columns=['Neighborhood', 'Count'],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    threshold_scale=threshold_scale,
    legend_name='Crime Rate in San Francisco')
sf_map
```

and I get an image like this:
[image]

but I need to have an image like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

the issue is in `key_on='feature.properties.name'`

should be `key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT'`

look at the JSON file and see where the lat/long coordinates are mapped to. 
In the world map example, in its JSON file it was 'name' but in san fransico it is 'DISCTRICT'

```
# download countries geojson file
!wget --quiet https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson -O san_francisco_nh.json

print('GeoJSON file downloaded!')
```

`sf_geo = r'san_francisco_nh.json'`

```
sanfran_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=sf_geo,
    data=nh_countindex,
    columns=['Neighborhood','Count'],
    key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT',
    fill_color='YlOrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Neighborhood Crime"
)

sanfran_map
```

[san fransico choropleth map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe9M0.png)